# Impact of different front tyre size

Tags: tires, peugeot

My Peugeot 5008 has just failed MOT because of wrong front tyres size. The driver side is `215/40/18/85/W` with (Tread, outside 5.5-centre 5- inside 5.1 mm) and the passenger side is `215/45/18/93/Y` with (Tread, outside 3.1-centre 3.4-inside 3.5) and. The garage is on the wrong side since they chose and changed the drive side tyre seven months ago.

My question is; should that had a bad impact on the car during the seven months ago? I want to understand if there is anything else should be checked before replacing the wrong sized tyres.

Comment: It could have been worse. You didn't crash. Seriously, having different sized tires on the same axle is just WRONG. Different speed ratings and load capacity isn't very clever, either.

Comment: And if you did have a crash, you then have to hope the insurance assessor doesn't notice - otherwise they probably wouldn't pay out on a car with a blatant automatic-MOT-failure fault that could have contributed to the cause of the accident.

Comment: Are the rims identical on both sides?